# TSQL Bulk Insert to use program files environment variable

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using MSSQL 2008, (though I have access to 2014 as well).  I am trying to write a script that will populate a table from data in a text file. This works just fine if I hard code the file name.

```
BULK INSERT mytable
FROM 'c:\Program Files\MyDirStructure\foo.dat'
```

However, I want to use the %programfiles% environment variable instead.  I tried putting that in directly, but of course it doesn't work since it's a string.  So I tried escaping the % signs with [], but again, I didn't figure that would work either.

So I tried using the $(ProgramFiles) syntax by build the path into a variable, but I am unclear on that syntax.  Additionally, you can't just shove a variable after the FROM keyword.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL and build the insert command as a string and then execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I did not know I needed to enable the "By default, open new queries in SQLCMD mode" under the Query Execution options.  Once I did that, I was able to figure it out.

```
DECLARE @folder_path NVARCHAR(255) = '$(ProgramW6432)' + '\my_path\'
SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT dbo.mytable
FROM ''' + @folder_path + 'foo.dat'''
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @sql
```

Not exactly sure what the security implications might be, but I am sure that's answered here someplace else.